# Jquery call to xml web service

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml, web-services

I'm having trouble trying to get information from a web service using Ajax jquery. My current code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
         CallWebService();
    });

function CallWebService() {
        var URL = "http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml";
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: URL,
            dataType: "xml",
            contentType: "application/xml; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        })
    }
```

When I run this code I get the following error:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

Any idea on how I can get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with the code. But it is with the way you are running the code. If you are using any server, host this page(on which this js is written) and then run it. Due to secutity concern, your request was blocked by browser.

Try running this page after hosting.